# How to check if my installation of Ubuntu is alright?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

I recently changed the size of the partition that contained my Ubuntu installation using Gparted from a live CD. I also moved it from one place to another. It was my first time and I hit the cancel button during my first try. I completed the task in my second try. But now I see that the size of the "computer" folder has shrunk by 2GB. Now I want to know if the system files are all right as I have backed up my files from the home folder before. How do I do that?

---

Some information:

**Related errors found in /var/log/syslog**

```
(AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM [ 12.287674] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro [ 40.663974] quiet_error: 150 callbacks suppressed 
[ 40.663979] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1 
[ 40.663984] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[ 40.663991] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1 
[ 40.664026] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[ 40.664032] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[ 40.664038] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[ 40.664044] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[ 40.664050] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[ 40.664056] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[ 40.664062] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0 
[1401354046.120788] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
```

**Contents of etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#    
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
# UUID=9bf1abba-55b4-466f-8f63-f0c2a94534b2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5110-FE96  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f16a051b-9c39-4d67-9bbc-48ba711004ed none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Output of 'mount' command**

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=likhon)
```

Answer (score 0):

First check `/var/log/syslog` for any errors. If you notice any specific errors them post them here.

If you are using a lvm based installation, check the outputs of `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` and verify them; or use `fdisk` / `parted` commands.

If you are suspect any data loss or corruption, you could run `fsck` on the modified partitions from the rescue mode.

Comment: Here are the errors that I found from syslog.

kernel: [ 4758.956780] option1 ttyUSB0: option_instat_callback: error -108

ModemManager[675]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): could not re-acquire serial port lock: (5) Input/output error

NetworkManager[826]: <warn> pppd pid 3768 exited with error: A modem hung up the phone

[    0.653546] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM

[   12.287674] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

[   40.663974] quiet_error: 150 callbacks suppressed

[   40.663979] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1

Comment: The following errors are from kernel.
[ 40.663984] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[ 40.663991] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 1
[   40.664026] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[   40.664032] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[   40.664038] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[   40.664044] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[   40.664050] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[   40.664056] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[   40.664062] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0

Comment: NetworkManager[731]: <error> [1401354046.120788] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name

{This is the last error.}

Comment: `sda3` has been remounted to RO possibly to to buffer I/O errors. Have you updated / checked `/etc/fstab` contents as you partition has been moved ? Have you managed to run `fsck` from rescue mode ?

Comment: Also could you provide the output of the `mount` command ? Its best to edit/update the original post with the additional information everytime.

Comment: Firstly I have updated my question with more informations that you wanted. Secondly after partitioning I turned my laptop on without any problem. Until now I haven't encountered any problem in ubuntu. I don't know about rescue mode, but I ran [fsck] command in normal mode and it gave me a warning. So I closed the terminal.

Comment: The current `mount` output shows that `/dev/sda3` is mounted properly as `rw`. However its could possibly that you are seeing some old messages while search through the `syslog`. If you are still interested in doing `fsck` from the [rescue/recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)